# How to remove elements closed in wrong way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anybody answer is it possible to delete elements closed in wrong way. Example (pay attention on div.separator):

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Content
  </div>

  <div class="separator" />

  <div class="inner">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery can't delete in standard way: `jQuery('div.separator').remove();`

Thanks

Comment: @Oded: But not the `div` element.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a matter of removing elements that is closed in the wrong way, it's a matter of what the browser does with the incorrect code.

The browser will parse the incorrect code as best it can, and create elements from it. The DOM will not contain any incorrectly closed elements, the browser will always create correct elements from the code, but it's not certain what elements it actually will create.

As there is no standard for how incorrect code should be interpreted, each browser will have their own way of fixing the code so that it can create elments from it. The `/` can be ignored, placing the `inner` div inside the `separator` div, the browser can accept the self-closed div eventhough it's incorrect, or the tag can just be ignored completely.

As there is no single way that this code will end up as elements, there is no single way of removing the element that will work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Guffa is obviously correct... after a bit of testing though, Firefox (v3.6), Chrome (8.0) & IE (8.0) all behave the same way, i.e. the second inner div becomes nested in the separator div.  For these three browsers at least you can:

```
var separator = $('div.separator');
separator.children().insertAfter(separator);
separator.remove();
```

Mileage on other browsers or even future versions of these browsers may vary.

Comment: What doctype did you use? The behaviour might differ between standards compliant mode and quirks mode, and depending on what version of HTML that is used.

Comment: Too true, I used XHTML 1.0 Strict for my test.